# What is the difference between displayChoice() and using .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find information about the use of JavaScript `displayChoice()`.

For example when should it be used over `document.getElementById("").innerHTML = x;`

What is the point of `displayChoice`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should never use `innerHTML`, you should either use `.textContent` if you're setting real text, or you should use be building a DOM off of whatever construction template `x` offers (e.g. an object that you use to guide which DOM nodes to build, in which nesting). As for `displayChoise`: that is guaranteed some kind of third party function, because choice is spelled "choice" in English, and the there is no function called `displayChoice` in standard JavaScript. So you'll have to read the documentation of whatever third party library that function is from.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply